# Is there a way to write a block function for a fighting game within python?

Tags: python

I am beginner in python and I need a second opinion to how i should implement a blocking feature

**Context**: Simple text based fighting game, all features work perfectly but when either the AI or player chooses to block the function a mess of things happen. Example-: The AI and Player no matter if they choose a punch or kick always block then do their attacks respectively.

Code:

```
import random

ai_health = 100
player_health = 100

def heal():
    global player_health
    heal = random.randint(0,20)
    player_health + heal 
    print("Player has healed for: ", player_health)


def kick_function():
    global ai_health
    if block_function("AI"):
        print("AI took no damage!")
    else:
        player_kick = random.randint(10, 20)
        ai_health -= player_kick
        print("AI has been hit for", player_kick)
        print("AI remaining health:", ai_health)


def AI_kick_function():
    global player_health
    if block_function("Player"):
        print("Player took no damage!")
    else:
        ai_kick = random.randint(10, 20)
        player_health -= ai_kick
        print("Player has been hit for", ai_kick)
        print("Player remaining health:", player_health)


def punch_function():
    global ai_health
    if block_function("AI"):
        print("AI took no damage!")
    else:
        player_punch = random.randint(5, 15)
        ai_health -= player_punch
        print("AI has been hit for", player_punch)
        print("AI remaining health:", ai_health)


def AI_punch_function():
    global player_health
    if block_function("Player"):
        print("Player took no damage!")
    else:
        ai_punch = random.randint(5, 15)
        player_health -= ai_punch  # Reduce player's health by the AI's punch result
        print("Player has been hit for", ai_punch)
        print("Player remaining health:", player_health)


def ai_function():
    ai_move = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
    if ai_move == 1:
        AI_punch_function()
    elif ai_move == 2:
        AI_kick_function()
    elif ai_move == 3:
        print("AI is blocking!")
        block_function("AI")

def block_function(character):
    block = random.randint(0, 1)
    if block == 1:
        print(character + " successfully blocked the attack!")
        return True
    else:
        print(character + " failed to block the attack!")
        return False

game_over = False
while not game_over:
    try:
        move = int(input("Enter 1 to punch, 2 to kick, 3 to block: "))
        if move == 1:
            punch_function()
        elif move == 2:
            kick_function()
        elif move == 3:
            block_function("Player")
        else:
            print("Invalid move. Please enter either of the following: 1 for punch, 2 for kick, 3 for block.\n")
            continue
        ai_function()
        if ai_health <= 0:
            print("You have defeated the AI!")
            game_over = True
        elif player_health <= 0:
            print("You have been defeated!")
            game_over = True
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")
```

Any and all help is appreciated, I have been tearing my head out rewriting and writing the feature. :)

I have tried to get this function to take a random 50% chance of weather or not when called blocks an attack or not. I would expect the blocking function to simply when true bypass the attacks and dont execute attacks, otherwise attacks work as intended. What resulted was that the function was called every time an option was chosen weather it was an attack or otherwise.

Code:

```
def block_function(character):
    block = random.randint(0, 1)
    if block == 1:
        print(character + " successfully blocked the attack!")
        return True
    else:
        print(character + " failed to block the attack!")
        return False`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you implemented a system where you are taking turns between you and the AI, and each player can either punch, kick or block. But on punch and kick, `block_function` is being called.

One way I'd fix this is to make global variables for the player or the AI blocks the next move. You can do this by adding the following variables right alongside `ai_health` and `player_health`...

```
player_blocks_next_move = False
ai_blocks_next_move = False
```

then add a `block_function_chosen` function to update the variables and use this function instead of `block_function` when they have chosen to block instead of attack. An example of this is demonstrated below.

```
def block_function_chosen(character):
    global ai_blocks_next_move, player_blocks_next_move
    if character == 'Player':
        player_blocks_next_move = True
    else:
        ai_blocks_next_move = True
```

then on every attack function, you can check if the attack should be blocked and call `block_function` like so...

```
def punch_function():
    global ai_health, ai_blocks_next_move
    if ai_blocks_next_move:
        ai_blocks_next_move = False
        if block_function('AI'):
            print('AI took no damage')
            return
    player_punch = random.randint(5, 15)
    ai_health -= player_punch
    print("AI has been hit for", player_punch)
    print("AI remaining health:", ai_health)
```

This checks if the AI should try to block the attack before taking damage. if the AI chose to block, then it sets `ai_blocks_next_move` to be false and tries to block by calling `block_function('AI')`. if it successfully blocks then it breaks out of the function without taking damage by calling an early return, if not then it takes the normal damage.

This implementation has not been tested but should give you an overall idea of how it could work.

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments I have added additional information to my response. I have now tested the code and believe I have fixed some of the errors it was having. I also refactored it to remove duplication. Below is the code I was testing...

```
import random

ai_health = 100
player_health = 100
player_blocks_next_move = False
ai_blocks_next_move = False



def take_move(character:str):
    if character == "Player":
        if player_health <= 0:
            return
        move = input("Enter 1 to punch, 2 to kick, 3 to block: ")
        character_to_attack = "AI"
    else:
        if ai_health <= 0:
            return
        move = random.choice(["1", "2", "3"])
        character_to_attack = "Player"

    if move == "1":
        attack_enemy(character_to_attack, "punch")
    elif move == "2":
        attack_enemy(character_to_attack, "kick")
    elif move == "3":
        print(f"{character} uses thier move to block their enemy's next move.")
        block_enemies_next_move(character)
    else:
        raise ValueError("You must enter either 1, 2, or 3")



def attack_enemy(character_to_attack:str, action:str):
    assert (action == "punch" or action == "kick"), f"Action must be either 'punch' or 'kick' not '{action}'."
    
    if action == "punch":
        damage = random.randint(5, 15)
    else:
        damage = random.randint(10, 20)

    if character_to_attack == "Player":
        global player_health, player_blocks_next_move
        if player_blocks_next_move:
            player_blocks_next_move = False
            if attack_is_blocked():
                print(f"{character_to_attack} successfully blocked a {action} and took no damage.")
                return
            print(f"{character_to_attack} failed to block an attack.")
        player_health -= damage
        health = player_health
    else:
        global ai_health, ai_blocks_next_move
        if ai_blocks_next_move:
            ai_blocks_next_move = False
            if attack_is_blocked():
                print(f"{character_to_attack} successfully blocked a {action} and took no damage.")
                return
            print(f"{character_to_attack} failed to block an attack.")
        ai_health -= damage
        health = ai_health
    if health > 0: 
        print(f"{character_to_attack} has been {action}ed for {damage} damage and has {health} health remaining.")
    else:
        print(f"{character_to_attack} has been {action}ed for {damage} damage and has been killed.")



def block_enemys_next_move(character:str):
    global ai_blocks_next_move, player_blocks_next_move
    if character == 'Player':
        player_blocks_next_move = True
        ai_blocks_next_move = False
    else:
        ai_blocks_next_move = True
        player_blocks_next_move = False



def attack_is_blocked():
    block = random.choice([0, 1])
    if block == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    


def main():
    game_over = False
    while not game_over:
        print() # creates a new line in the terminal to seperate each move
        try:
            take_move("Player")
            take_move("AI")
        except ValueError as value_error:
            print(value_error)
        
        if ai_health <= 0:
            print("You have defeated the AI!")
            game_over = True
        elif player_health <= 0:
            print("You have been defeated!")
            game_over = True

main()
```

As you can see I combined all attack moves into a single attack function, made the functions have a more descriptive name, created a main function for the while loop, and moved created a unified `take_move` function. The input type in the `take_move` function has been changed from an integer to a string to make error handling easier. In the `block_enemys_next_move` function, I fixed an error that could arise if both players decided to use their turn to block. I also removed the heal function as it was not being used.

This should fix your problems and make your code easier to work with.

Comment: Great thinking! Wish I had thought of that sooner small problem though is that when you implement your fix into part of the code it seems to not let any damage to be done regardless of weather or not blocking was initiated.  Still really great problem solving skills! Especially for code that has not been tested.

Comment: it might be because it isn't updating the global variable, can you check my updated code and see if that fixed the issue?

Comment: I made reference to the global variable both inside  punch_function and block_function_chosen. It might have been because it wasn't properly updating the global variable. If you are still having problems, can you tell me what is printing to the console?

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting but after extensively testing your implementation it seemed to have worked! but on a slight catch you see am a beginner in python so correct me if am wrong please but you see when a player blocks it essentially blocks twice because with the "if block_function('AI')" actually for some reason calls the function and since we call them twice both for the punch and kick function it essentially blocks twice. Checkout the main post up top to check my tachy and probably messed up workaround. Really thankful for your input alantbarlow!

Comment: @milo, I have added to my answer to address the additional issues you were having.

Comment: That sir has got to be some of the cleanest and solid piece of coding I've seen, this block function started out in frustration but now am learning way more then I otherwise would've if I had not tried to reach out for a better alternative, this does solve a lot of problems in fact not just the block function itself. Although if i may say something, the AI seems to be able to hit back whilst blocking which may as well be considered a game play feature. Thanks so much for your help you truly have helped me understand coding with your implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your block function not random, I would make it so that when the AI/Person is attacked it can choose if it wants to block or counter attack, so let's say when the AI/Person is attacked they have a bar or threshold of whether or not they can block or counter attack.

That bar is filled up overtime during the fight based on how many times you successfully land an attack or not, if you land an attack your bar increases.

Once the bar is at a minimum benchmark you can choose to block when faced with an attack and what the block does it decreases the amount of health the player loses by giving the player health when they are hurt. So you do not need to implement something in the block function that cancels the attack function because that's not a block. You are still getting hurt if you block an attacks but you are losing way less damage than if you did not block instead. So when they choose block if they can choose block you give them a fair amount of health back instantly after they take the attacks and you just change how the sequence plays out for the user.

Now if the user's bar has filled up or reached a higher benchmark compared to the block benchmark they have the option to counter-attacks the attack on them. What this does is that it gives the user enough health to tank whatever attack they were faced with while giving the attacker damage since it is a counter attack.

You need to implement this by using true or false variables with counters and loops. If the counter of the bar reaches a certain amount and user chose block and user is being attacked they can be given the amount of health the attack would have taken minus 1 quarter or whatever amount you choose.

Comment: Really forward thinking! I like the threshold solution, ultimately though i would rather keep the code I have at the moment but it is a interesting and deeply thought out idea. Perhaps someone else with my problem could implement your solution :)

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not being able to implement it. It is a challenge for myself.